# How to host my github-flavored-markdown gist as a webpage

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

I have created a "todo" Gist using GitHub Flavored Markdown on GitHub. Is there any way to host it on my online DigitalOcean server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gists [can be embedded with JavaScript](https://help.github.com/articles/about-gists/#embedding-gists):

> You can embed a gist in any text field that supports Javascript, such as a blog post. To get the embed code, click the clipboard icon next to the **Embed** URL of a gist.

Paste the `<script>` tag copied from the Gist into a web page hosted on your server, e.g.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>To do list</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>To do list</h1>
    <script src="https://gist.github.com/user/gist_id.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! The js will just provide a read only view. But what I wanted to do was being able to click on the todo list and that would commit the changes to my gist without having the visit the repo. Is that possibe?

Comment: @ShashankShekhar, I'm not aware of any way to do that.

Comment: since you answered what you interpreted from the question, I'll mark the answer as accepted. Thanks